# Dynamic Scheduling with ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, scheduled-tasks, hangfire

We want to create background job scheduling. 
Job may be vary by daily,on demand.

Backgound job scheduling can be easily integrated by using HangFire,FluentScheduling library.

But all method for scheduling should be called dynamic, to send push notification to user of application.

There will be one main Recuring job which is going to be fired on every 5 minutes and there are other child job should be created dynamically means one job for one notification.

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.Write("Easy!"), Cron.Daily);
how can i get job id for this job and pass to other child job.

how can it will be achieved in asp.core ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save the schedules (permanent) and the demands (temporary) somewhere (e.g. a database). Than schedule the background job to run every few seconds to check in the DB, if there is something to do.

You should also have a look into HostedServices in ASP.NET Core to run background tasks.

Comment: thanks .For use IHostedService interface service how to deal with start and stop of service?

Comment: The services are starting immediately and are stopig when the application stops. Usually on the StartAsync method you create a loop and call whatever you need to call: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/11/18/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/